# Envoy raise Class 'Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider' not found?

Tags: laravel-5

Working with envoy in laravel 5.7 on production server I run composer with --no-dev keys:

```
@task( 'composer', ['on'=>$on] )
    cd {{ $release_number }}

    composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --prefer-dist
```

As I do not need dev part on production.

But I see error in envoy output:

```
lardeployer@NN.NNN.N.NN]: > @php artisan package:discover
[lardeployer@NN.NNN.N.NN]: In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
[lardeployer@NN.NNN.N.NN]: Class 'Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider' not found
[lardeployer@NN.NNN.N.NN]: Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

In my config/app.php file I see :

```
   'providers' => [
        ...
        Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class,
```

I think that this definition raise an error.
How to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you shouldn't put the  `Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class` within the `config/app.php` file.

as mentioned within the  [package doc Barryvdh](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar#laravel-55) here

> Laravel 5.5 uses Package Auto-Discovery, so doesn't require you to
>   manually add the ServiceProvider.

in that case, you don't need to put the Service provider within the `config/app.php` file because as mentioned in the installation instruction :

> The Debugbar will be enabled when APP_DEBUG is true.

you can find `APP_DEBUG` within `.env` file.

Answer (score 7):

Enter the `boostrap/cache` folder and remove all the files it contains. After removing run the command:

```
php artisan package:discover
```

Answer (score -1):

Please show us your `composer.json` file and make sure that you have ran `composer update barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` and `composer dump-autoload`.